# How to display Show Case views one after another

Tags: android

> I have 4 buttons.I need to give showcase views for each button.But the
>   problem is that when creating show case views for each button on
>   Oncreate,all showcase view display simultaneously.How can i display it
>   one after the other?.
>
> Oncreate Code

```
 target = new ViewTarget(R.id.shutdown, this);show_showcase(target, "Tutorial", "Click this button...");
   target = new ViewTarget(R.id.track, this);show_showcase(target, "Tutorial", "Click this button to...");
   target = new ViewTarget(R.id.lock, this);show_showcase(target,"Tutorial","Click this button to...");
   target = new ViewTarget(R.id.unlock, this);show_showcase(target,"Tutorial","Click this to ...");
```

> function show_showcase

```
void show_showcase(final ViewTarget target,final String title,final String content) {

   Selection.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {

                   new ShowcaseView.Builder(Selection.this, true)
                   .setTarget(target)
                   .setContentTitle(title)
                   .setContentText(content)
                   .setStyle(R.style.CustomShowcaseTheme)
                   .build();

       }
   });
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. I was using showcase view version 5 which does not have showcase views class. Downgraded and added version 4 to my Android Studio project and this fixed it.

1. Select legacy release of showcase view
2. Download the showcaseview library
3. Add it to application
4. Use showcaseviews class

Example of this class is given in sample  app in showcase view library

Answer (score 0):

use `overrideButtonclick()` and create a new showcase component inside the `onClickListener()` function.